# What are the Java components necessary to posting an Ad from Admob?

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

Does one simply include the xml for an ad only, or is there something else to add in Java?

In my situation, this is what I currently have for the ad in my xml:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Is there something missing in the MainActivity.java class?

Comment: Why dont you try out and see if it works ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link should help you: [AdMob Android Integration](http://www.stonetrip.com/developer/wiki/index.php?title=AdMob_Android_Integration#Step_by_Step).  It covers everything from importing the library to updating the manifest to the XML layout and onCreate.  Should get you up and running.